# Read multiple files using multiple threads in c

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


int file_index = 0;         // index for array[500];


struct webData {
    char web_names [255];           
};


void *thread(void *wData_element)
{
    struct webData *temp = wData_element;

    FILE *fp; 
    char line[255]="";      // hold each line;
    fp = fopen(temp->web_names, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: File open failure.");
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(line,255, fp);
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) 
{


    DIR * dir_pointer;          // define a dir pointer;
    struct dirent * entry;      // entry under dir;
    //char *dir = "./data/";
    dir_pointer = opendir("./data/"); // assign dir location into dir pointer


    // declare the struct wData array for each file. 
    struct webData wData[500];
    // declare the threads array.
    pthread_t tid_array[500];


    while( (entry = readdir(dir_pointer)) != NULL)
    {

        if(entry->d_type == DT_REG) // avoid the . and .. dir;
        {

            char full_path[255];     
            full_path[0] = '\0';    // initilize the string;

            strcat(full_path, "./data/");  // concatenate file directory;
            strcat(full_path, entry->d_name);    // concatenate filename;
            strcpy(wData[file_index].web_names, full_path); // store file name into web_names array;


            pthread_create(&tid_array[file_index], NULL, thread, &wData[file_index]);



            file_index++;   // increase the file index for next file.


        }


    }


    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)      
    {
        pthread_join(tid_array[i], NULL);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

---

For this program:

There are 500 files in the data folder.

For each file, I create a thread to do some action on the file.

After I iterate all 500 files. I join all the threads.

**My question is:**

How can I create 10 threads, and each thread does some action on exact 50 files?

How can I make sure each thread only handle 50 files since they are running concurrently?

For example:

thread 1 handles files number from 1-50

thread 2 handles files number from 51-100

.

.

.

Thanks a lot for any related source or example.

Comment: Are you linking `pthread` in your build process?

Comment: @danielu13 thanks, it works right now. How about my question?

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment, so I can't give a detailed answer but you'll want to create a thread-safe queue of files or filename that each thread reads from. If a thread tries to read from the queue and it is empty, then the thread returns and is joined. To be even more flexible, you may want to look at doing this over the network. You can use sockets or I am quite partial to ZeroMQ for such tasks. There are also other similar libraries that you could create a networked queue. For threads, you could just have it connect locally and feed threads that connect to it.

Comment: And if you go the ZeroMQ route, they have a quite good guide online that is its main source of documentation. Look at PUSH/PULL or pipeline in that guide and it'll probably help you out. Some of the higher level ZMQ bindings also have some more advanced threading functionality. Note that does bring in a dependency on another library, which you may or may not want.

Comment: You should pass a different argument to each of your thread functions that tells it which files to process.  Your thread function will then only process the files it was told to process (you write obedient functions, don't you?).  If you're scanning a directory, each thread will open it, skip the `.` and `..` entries, and then an appropriate number of other entries before starting to process the files.

Comment: I didn't think of this in my previous comments, but you should make sure you do indeed need to do this in a multithreaded manner. Disk I/O can easily be a bottleneck and doing it in multiple threads can actually hurt performance. It may be worth considering reading your files from one thread and passing the file contents to do processing in another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you declare a parameter-struct for the threads

```
typedef struct thread_param_s {
     // each thread will get an array of webData-files
     struct webData* data;
     // number of elements
     int n;    
} thread_param_t;
```

You create this param-struct for each thread, fill it accordingly and pass it in `pthread_create` instead of the `wData*`

Now you adjust your current code

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


int file_index = 0;         // index for array[500];


struct webData {
    char web_names [255];           
};


void *thread(void *param)
{
    thread_param_t* thread_param = (thread_param_t*)param;
    int i;
    // iterate through all files
    for (i = 0; i < thread_param->n; i++) {
        struct webData *temp = thread_param->data + i;

        FILE *fp; 
        char line[255]="";      // hold each line;
        fp = fopen(temp->web_names, "r");

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error: File open failure.");
        }
        else
        {
            fgets(line,255, fp);
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) 
{


    DIR * dir_pointer;          // define a dir pointer;
    struct dirent * entry;      // entry under dir;
    //char *dir = "./data/";
    dir_pointer = opendir("./data/"); // assign dir location into dir pointer


    // declare the struct wData array for each file. 
    struct webData wData[500];
    // declare the threads array.



    while( (entry = readdir(dir_pointer)) != NULL)
    {

        if(entry->d_type == DT_REG) // avoid the . and .. dir;
        {

            char full_path[255];     
            full_path[0] = '\0';    // initilize the string;

            strcat(full_path, "./data/");  // concatenate file directory;
            strcat(full_path, entry->d_name);    // concatenate filename;
            strcpy(wData[file_index].web_names, full_path); // store file name into web_names array;

            file_index++;   // increase the file index for next file.
            // just fill wData here

        }


    }

    pthread_t tid_array[10];
    thread_param_t thread_param[10];
    int thread_counter = 0;

    // number of files for each thread
    int step = file_index / 10;
    int i;

    // create all threads
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)      
    {
       thread_param[i].n = step;
       thread_param[i].data = wData + step * i;

       pthread_create(&tid_array[i], NULL, thread, thread_param + i);
    }
    // the last thread may get more data, because of integer rounding
    thread_param[i].n = file_index - step * i;
    thread_param[i].data = wData + step * i;

    pthread_create(&tid_array[i], NULL, thread, thread_param + i);



    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)      
    {
        pthread_join(tid_array[i], NULL);
    }


    return 0;
}
```